# Selectize required tag breaks placeholder

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, selectize.js

I'm building a laravel project (version 9) and I need to use selectize.js for my select inputs.

I need to show a placeholder like "Select product" so users can click on it, search for items and choose one. And I need this field to be **required**.

Here's a sample select input :

```
<select name="product_id" id="select_product" class="form-control my-3">
    <option value="">Select product</option>
    @foreach($products as $product)
            <option value="{{$product->id}}" data-price="{{$product->price}}" data-stock="{{$product->stock}}">{{$product->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

This one works fine, it's not required though. And submiting the form with this field empty throws an error, I need it to be required on the front-end level.

BUT, when I add `required` to the select input, it doesn't show ANY of the options I'm loading inside select box with foreach loop. Doesn't even show a dropdown when I click on it.

Is there a way to have a placeholder and make the field required at the same time in select.js? If not, do you know any alternative to select.js that works with Laravel?

I also tried giving a placeholder through selectize function with JS, nothing changed, it shows placeholder but no items being shown (when the input has `required` tag).

```
<select name="customer_id" class="form-control" id="select_customer" required>
    <option value=""></option>
    @forelse($customers as $customer)
        <option value="{{$customer->id}}">{{$customer->name}}</option>
    @empty
        <option value="" selected disabled>No customer found</option>
    @endforelse
</select>
```

```
$('select').selectize({
    placeholder: 'Select something',
});
```

Simplest way to put it : Select input doesn't show any options when I add `required` tag to it. (I'm loading options with laravel blade foreach loop.)

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: I don't think it's a PHP problem but I'm not 100% certain, it might be happening because selectize is not compatible with Laravel foreach loops... Select input doesn't show any options when I add `required` tag to it. That's the simplest way to put it.